# Same build/source code for multiple machines in Yocto

Tags: build, embedded-linux, yocto

The question I have is as follows:

So I already have a board whose code is to be ported to another board but the second board can also have its own sepcific layers and content. 
And If i build the image for the first machine, it should have the contents of the first machine alone and not the second machine whereas for the second machine, it should have both layers.

I am thinking of using the build environment variable in machinename.conf but i am not sure of the approach. Can someome point me in the right direction.

Comment: I think BBLAYERS will have to contain all layers for both machines, but you could use BBMAKS to remove layers per machine:

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-BBMASK

Comment: You can split your first layer with machine specific only in one layer and common stuff in another layer, and import the common layer in your second machine specific only layer. You can also use overrides, like `BITBAKEVAR_machine1 = "stuff1"` `BITBAKEVAR_machine2 = "stuff2"  `

Comment: But do these changes go into local.conf or machine.conf ? @Nayfe

Comment: Also I was thinking of using env variable and do an IMAGE_INSTALL_append to install recipes by doing d.getVar() in machinename.conf